differential volume element under characteristics
I see there is a statement about the method of characteristics: in 2D and 3D, we let $y=x-lv$ where it says we go from $x$ for length $l$ following the direction $v$. To do a change of variable, it follows
$$
dy=|S^{d-1}||x-y|^{d-1}dldv
$$
where |S^{d-1}| is the surface area of the unit sphere in $S^{d-1}$. Can anyone help me fill the gap between $dy=-vdl$ and the above statement?

Think through spherical coordinates centered at the origin.

However, my confusion is about how we explicitly write upon the direction vector v in cartesian coordinates. for example 2D, we can use polar. but theta in polar represents the angle. How would you write y=x-lv in polar representation then? like what is v here

$v$ is then a vector on the unit circle, just as it is a vector on $S^{d-1}$ in your original set-up. Now that you mention it, I don't think $|S^{d-1}|$ belongs in that formula.

so you are saying i should only consider $dy=|x-y|^{d-1}dldv$? and the jabocian determinant is only $|x-y|^{d-1}$?

Yes. Work it out for polar and spherical coordinates.
